# Flutter , IconButton not working when using alignment or margin or padding

Tags: android, flutter, padding

```
 appBar: new AppBar(
      leading: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_forward),
            onPressed: () {
              _nextPage(1);
            },
            tooltip: 'Next',
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 360.0),
          ),
          IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
            onPressed: () {
              _nextPage(-1);
            },
            tooltip: 'Previous',
          ),
        ],
      ),
     ),
```

Blockquote

> The two IconButtons , the first one doesn't work but the second does , when you remove the padding it works fine , How should i do this ? , and using Containers wouldn't help as much because they take space too , so what to do ?

Comment: "not working" - what do you mean?

Answer (score 5):

You have many errors there .

**First**
You are using a `Stack`, stack will put your widgets over the other, so you have to specify the position using `Positioned` or `Align`.

**Second**
If you check the source code , you'll find there is a width limit for the `leading` Widget.

```
if (leading != null) {
  leading = new ConstrainedBox(
    constraints: const BoxConstraints.tightFor(width: _kLeadingWidth),
    child: leading,
  );
}
```

> where _kLeadingWidth = 56

**1st Solution**

Replace your `Stack` widget by `Row` widget, if you do this, you'll get an overflow exception because the size of your two `IconButtons` exceed the width > 56.

**Final Solution (you can find more)**

Remove your `IconButton` and use an `Icon` wrapped by InkWell (in order to receive the tap)

```
      return Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          leading: Row(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: <Widget>[
              InkWell(
                  onTap: () => print("1"),
                  child: Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
                      child: const Icon(Icons.arrow_forward))),
              InkWell(
                  onTap: () => print("2"),
                  child: Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
                      child: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back))),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
```

Comment: Very helpful, Thank you